# discord.py i get error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My code:

```py
@client.command()
async def iponeargoopelda(ctx):
   with open("id users2.txt") as f:
      data = f.readlines()
      user = client.get_user(data[1])
      await user.send('hey')
```

The above code produced this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command iponeargoopelda:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\Desktop\Nukebot.py", line 28, in iponeargoopelda
    await user.send('hey')
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
   
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

This code gets the id from `id users2.txt` and sends it to a user.

How would I be able to send a dm to all the ids in the txt file?

`id users2.txt`

```
752773841885069333
592717639105773589
601008862178443267
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. The issue with before you were using `\n` in the id and getting a user from that. As a result, Discord does not filter the input and is something you need to do.

```py
@client.command()
async def iponeargoopelda(ctx):
    with open("doc.txt") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for user_id in data:
            user = client.get_user(user_id.replace("\n",""))
            await user.send('hey')
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `readlines` method there's the new line delimiter, your list after reading looks like this:

```py
['752773841885069333\n', '592717639105773589\n', '601008862178443267\n']
```

Also it's worth noticing that the ID's in the list are strings, instead of integers, to fix both problems you can use a bit of list comprehension

```py
with open("id users2.txt") as f:
    data = [int(elem[:-1]) for elem in f.readlines()] # You can also use the `str.removesufix` method if you're using python3.9+
```

The list will be of the correct format

```py
[752773841885069333, 592717639105773589, 601008862178443267]
```

To send a message to all users you can use a for loop.

Your code fixed

```py
@client.command()
async def iponeargoopelda(ctx):
    with open("id users2.txt") as f:
        data = [int(elem[:-1]) for elem in f.readlines()]

    for user_id in data:
        user = client.get_user(user_id)
        await user.send('hey')
```